# Linux debian how to disable TCP checksum verification?

Tags: networking, debian, vmware-esxi, tcp

While trying to open a TCP Port to host B from A, I figure out there's a problem in the 3 way TCP handshake between the two hosts.

Client/Host A send a SYN to host B, Host B send a SYN/ACK, then host A send a RST packet.

I sniffed packets in wireshark, and found that the SYN/ACK packet does not have the same TCP checksum after it has been sent by A and received by B. Otherwise it is the exact same packet. Wireshark mark the packet as "ACKed unseen segment".

I do not have any hops between the two machines. The two hosts are VMs in VMware ESXi hosts . The VMs are in different hosts. They are directly connected in the same VLAN in ESXi. The client VMs is on ESXi v4.1.0. I opened all the firewall for my tests. And finally I totally turned off the TCP checksum offload. I did the same test with a VM that is on the same host, same result. The client VM runs debian Jessie 8.8, and the other VMs are debian wheezy.

I'm suspecting ESXi is modifying the checksum between the two machine.

As I don't have much experience with VMware ESXi, and debugging it, I'd like to know how to "disable" the checksum TCP? It would be a workaround for now and test that the problem really come from the checksum.

I tried to add a iptables mangle rule like that on host A:

`iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -s #IP_HOST_B# -o eth0 -j CHECKSUM --checksum-fill`

But doesn't change anything.

Comment: Presumably you're using either a Virtual Standard Switch or a Virtual Distributed Switch on your ESXi hosts? if so are you aware they're both L2 switches - by default they don't even recognise that you're even using IP, they're just dealing with ethernet packets/frames. Does this happen when the VMs are on the same host or only when they're on different hosts?

Comment: What ESXi version are you running? What Debian version are you running? Do you have this problem when the VMs are running on the same host or only when they are running on different hosts? Do you have standard or distributed virtual switches?

Comment: Can you post the packet capture somewhere?

Comment: I added the debian version information, tested with two VMs on the same host, ESXi version is 4.1.0. I can post the network packets, but don't where?